# How can I change Connection String on dbContext with EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I'm Building a WCF service application with the next structure:

> WCF Client -> WCF Service -> Business Layer -> Repository -> EF6

My app requires that the service listen to multiple clients, each of wich could request data from different databases (Identical model). So client use a Connect Method to tell the service wich database it needs to use. 
To do this i use a class that creates a connectionstring. My problem is how to tell the context to change it's connection string. So far I manage to resolve this by overwriting the constructor like this:

```
public partial class OhmioNETEntities : DbContext
{
    public OhmioNETEntities() : base(SingleConnection.ConString)
    {
    }
}
```

This works, but the problem is that if I refresh the model, this code is lost and replaced by

```
public partial class OhmioNETEntities : DbContext
{
    public OhmioNETEntities() : base("name=OhmioNETEntities")
    {
    }
}
```

Is there a best way of doing this?
Thanks!

**EDIT**
Thanks to all for the help, but i can't get it to work.
As suggested I add a new file with this code:

```
public partial class OhmioNETEntities : DbContext
{
    public OhmioNETEntities(string ConString) 
    {
    }
}
```

and when I create the Context I use:

```
context = new OhmioNETEntities(SingleConnection.ConString);
```

and get this error:

> {"The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception. If you wish to use Database First or Model First, then make sure that the Entity Framework connection string is included in the app.config or web.config of the start-up project. If you are creating your own DbConnection, then make sure that it is an EntityConnection and not some other type of DbConnection, and that you pass it to one of the base DbContext constructors that take a DbConnection. To learn more about Code First, Database First, and Model First see the Entity Framework documentation here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=394715"}

Any Idea Why? thanks!

Comment: You can edit the model.tt template file to make your change persist each time the code is generated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your context is built as a [partial class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/wa80x488.aspx) which means you can add your own constructor. In the same project, add this class:

```
public partial class OhmioNETEntities
{
    public OhmioNETEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Now wherever you need your context, you can do this:

```
var myContext = new OhmioNETEntities("connection string here");
```

Answer (score 1):

We have to provide entity connection string in DbContext

```
  SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
    DataSource = "SOURAV-PC", // Server name
    InitialCatalog = "efDB",  //Database
            UserID = "sourav",         //Username
            Password = "mypassword",  //Password
        };
        //Build an Entity Framework connection string

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
            Metadata =   "res://*/testModel.csdl|res://*/testModel.ssdl|res://*/testModel.msl",
            ProviderConnectionString = sqlString.ToString()
        };
        return entityString.ConnectionString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a new file that continues the partial class `ohmioNETEntities`. In there, you can define a new constructor that takes in a string param, that calls the base constructor.

So - here's your new file ( which will not be overwritten when re-generating entities ) :

```
public partial class OhmioNETEntities {
    public OhmioNETEntities(string connectionstring) : base(connectionstring) {
    }
}
```

That's the beauty of partial classes ( and the reason the code generation template uses them here ). You can safe keep your own logic in those while still being able to generate everything.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SMISContext : DbContext
{
    public SMISContext()
        : base("SMISContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SMISContext>(null);


    }
```

You can provide your connection string in web config as follows

in your webconfig:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SMISContext" connectionString="Data source=FARKA-DC\ISIMS;initial catalog=SMISJULY_08; user id=sa; password=1qazXSW@;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To everyone. Find it myself, I follow all your advices and adapt it to my needs:

```
public partial class OhmioNETEntities : DbContext
{
    public OhmioNETEntities(string ConString) : base(ConString)
    {
    }
}
```

And to create the context:

```
context = new OhmioNETEntities(SingleConnection.ConString);
```

Answer (score 0):

In inicialize class procedure, insert the new connection string.

```
public OhmioNETEntities() : base(SingleConnection.ConString)
{
    base.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "new connection string here";    
}
```

If you need try insert a text variable @password in SingleConnection.ConString and replace in base.Database.Connection.ConnectionString. It works fine!